# How to get last date in updated json file?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, urllib

i am getting my data from json file and the data are updated evryday. **How can i get only the latests date in that json file ? for each country of cores**

Here is my code for getting the json data:

```
# Print Daily Updated Report from JSON file from this (URL)

import json
import urllib.request, json 

url = "https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/json/"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

obj = json.loads(data)
for p in obj['records']:
        a= ('Country: ' + p['countriesAndTerritories'])
        b= ('Date: ' + p['dateRep'])
        c=('Cases: ' + str(p['cases']))
        d=('Deaths: ' + str(p['deaths']))
        AllData = (a,b,c,d)
        print(AllData)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the elements and then `max()` with custom `key=` to search for latest date within the group. For example:

```
import json
import urllib.request, json
from itertools import groupby
from datetime import datetime

url = "https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/json/"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

obj = json.loads(data)

for country, group in groupby(
    sorted(obj["records"], key=lambda k: k["countriesAndTerritories"]),
    lambda k: k["countriesAndTerritories"],
):
    mx = max(group, key=lambda k: datetime.strptime(k["dateRep"], "%d/%m/%Y"))
    print(country)
    print(json.dumps(mx, indent=4))
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```json
Austria
{
    "dateRep": "04/05/2021",
    "day": "04",
    "month": "05",
    "year": "2021",
    "cases": 888,
    "deaths": 25,
    "countriesAndTerritories": "Austria",
    "geoId": "AT",
    "countryterritoryCode": "AUT",
    "popData2020": "8901064",
    "continentExp": "Europe"
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Belgium
{
    "dateRep": "04/05/2021",
    "day": "04",
    "month": "05",
    "year": "2021",
    "cases": 0,
    "deaths": 0,
    "countriesAndTerritories": "Belgium",
    "geoId": "BE",
    "countryterritoryCode": "BEL",
    "popData2020": "11522440",
    "continentExp": "Europe"
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bulgaria
{
    "dateRep": "04/05/2021",
    "day": "04",
    "month": "05",
    "year": "2021",
    "cases": 631,
    "deaths": 56,
    "countriesAndTerritories": "Bulgaria",
    "geoId": "BG",
    "countryterritoryCode": "BGR",
    "popData2020": "6951482",
    "continentExp": "Europe"
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need a ***latest_day*** variable library

Full code is:

```
import json
import urllib.request, json 

url = "https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/json/"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

obj = json.loads(data)
latest_day = obj['records'][0]['dateRep']

for p in obj['records']:
    if p['dateRep'] == latest_day:
        a= ('Country: ' + p['countriesAndTerritories'])
        b= ('Date: ' + p['dateRep'])
        c=('Cases: ' + str(p['cases']))
        d=('Deaths: ' + str(p['deaths']))
        AllData = (a,b,c,d)
        print(AllData)
```